# Is there any occasion when women's team faced men's team in any sport match?

Tags: football, international-sports

Does anyone remember a football or any other sport match when women's faced men's team, whether it is international or league or domestic match?

Comment: Are you talking any kind of match, even just for fun, or an actual match that mattered during the season?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad until some reasonable criteria are given to avoid "we played a girls vs boys match at school at school when I was 10" answers.

Answer (score 2):

I was pretty sure I'd seen this mentioned before and Wikipedia supports it.  [Dick Kerr's ladies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick,_Kerr%27s_Ladies_F.C.) who were an extremely famous and popular exhibition ladies team played some mens teams certainly whilst on a [tour of the US in 1922.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick,_Kerr%27s_Ladies_F.C.#American_Tour_.281922.29)

So it certainly has occurred.

Answer (score 2):

In preparation of international tournaments like the World Hockey League, Champions Trophy, World Championships or the Olympic Games, the Dutch women's field hockey team played several friendlies against male teams.

- Against [Cartouche](http://nos.nl/video/648465-hockeysters-oranje-oefenen-tegen-mannen.html) (Dutch, with video).
- Against [Hudito](http://www.omroepwest.nl/sport/17-05-2014/gelijkspel-hockeydames-oranje-tegen-mannen-hudito) (Dutch)
- [This website](http://denhaagfm.nl/2014/04/02/nederlandse-hockeysters-oefenen-tegen-mannenteams/) (Dutch) reports also of a match against Klein Zwitserland.